# Realm object not up to date

Tags: kotlin, realm, realm-list

I have a singleton `TimeManager` that permanently listens to changes in my `Session` to perform backoffice stuff.

In the code below, I'm adding a `TimeInterval` object to the `timeIntervals` `RealmList` of my `Session` object after deleting the existing ones, each time a `Session` changes.

On a first change triggered by the UI, everything is fine and my `Session` has one `TimeInterval`object.

On a second change triggered by the UI, what's going wrong is that nothing is deleted when I do `session.timeIntervals.deleteAllFromRealm()` as `session.timeIntervals` is empty, as the `Timber` log shows.

So it looks like the `timeIntervals` `RealmList` is not up to date, but calling `realm.refresh()` does not solve the issue. If I restart my app between the two changes, everything is fine.

I've tried to add an `onSuccess` listener just to see if it was called and it does. There is pretty much no lag as I'm doing this on an empty Realm.

Here is the code:

```
object TimeManager {

    var sessions: RealmResults<Session>? = null

    private val sessionIdsToProcess = mutableSetOf<String>()
    
    fun configure() {} // launch init

    fun sessionChanged(session: Session) {
        this.sessionIdsToProcess.add(session.id)
    }

    init {

        val realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()

        sessions = realm.where(Session::class.java).findAllAsync()
        sessions?.addChangeListener { _, _ ->

            if (sessionIdsToProcess.isNotEmpty()) {

                realm.executeTransactionAsync({ asyncRealm ->

                Timber.d("in asyncRealm {")

                val sessions = sessionIdsToProcess.mapNotNull { asyncRealm.findById(Session::class.java, it) }
                sessionIdsToProcess.clear()

                for (session in sessions) {
                    Timber.d("   Session id = ${session.id}")
                    Timber.d("   Session time intervals count = ${session.timeIntervals.size}")
                    session.timeIntervals.deleteAllFromRealm()
                    val fti = TimeInterval()
                    session.timeIntervals.add(fti)
                    asyncRealm.insertOrUpdate(session)
                }
                Timber.d("}")

                }, {
                    Timber.d("executeTransactionAsync onSuccess listener...")
                    val timeIntervals = realm.where(TimeInterval::class.java).findAll()
                    Timber.d("Total timeIntervals count = ${timeIntervals.size}")

                    timeIntervals.forEach {
                        Timber.d(">>> Time interval session count = ${it.sessions?.size}, session id = ${it.sessions?.firstOrNull()?.id}")
                    }

                }, {})
            }
        }
    }
}


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    [...]

    // action triggered by a button
    private fun updateSession() {
    
        Timber.d("Update session")
    
        session.size = Random.nextInt()
        TimeManager.sessionChanged(session)
    
        realm.executeTransactionAsync {
            it.insertOrUpdate(this.session)
        }
    
    }

}

open class Session : RealmObject() {

    @PrimaryKey
    var id = UUID.randomUUID().toString()

    var size: Int? = null

    var timeIntervals: RealmList<TimeInterval> = RealmList()

}

open class TimeInterval : RealmObject() {

    @PrimaryKey
    var id = UUID.randomUUID().toString()

    @LinkingObjects("timeIntervals")
    val sessions: RealmResults<Session>? = null

}
```

Here are the Timber logs:

First change:

> D/MainActivity: Update session
> D/TimeManager: in asyncRealm {
> D/TimeManager:    Session id = 0e6e4eab-61a6-4848-bcb4-ce805b41de16
> D/TimeManager:    Session time intervals count = 0
> D/TimeManager: }
> D/TimeManager: executeTransactionAsync onSuccess listener...
> D/TimeManager: Total timeIntervals count = 1
> D/TimeManager: >>> Time interval session count = 1, session id = 0e6e4eab-61a6-4848-bcb4-ce805b41de16

Second change:

> D/MainActivity: Update session
> D/TimeManager: in asyncRealm {
> D/TimeManager:    Session id = 0e6e4eab-61a6-4848-bcb4-ce805b41de16
> D/TimeManager:    Session time intervals count = 0
> D/TimeManager: }
> D/TimeManager: executeTransactionAsync onSuccess listener...
> D/TimeManager: Total timeIntervals count = 2
> D/TimeManager: >>> Time interval session count = 0, session id = null
> D/TimeManager: >>> Time interval session count = 1, session id = 0e6e4eab-61a6-4848-bcb4-ce805b41de16

Now if I stop my app after the first change and launch it again, here are the logs I get for the second change (the id changes because I started from scratch):

> TimeManager: Session id = 534e9294-6462-4efa-aaf9-834d085aa2ba
> TimeManager: Session time intervals count = 1
> TimeManager: executeTransactionAsync onSuccess listener...
> TimeManager: Total timeIntervals count = 1
> TimeManager: >>> Time interval session count = 1, session id = 534e9294-6462-4efa-aaf9-834d085aa2ba

How to make sure that `session.timeIntervals` is up to date?

Comment: The question and code are a little vague; when you say - *How to be sure that my objects are up to date?* - which objects are you referring to? Did you do some basic troubleshooting by adding a breakpoint and stepping through the code line by line, inspecting the vars and code execution until you spot something unexpected? Can you clarify what's being asked and include you troubleshooting? Which line fails?

Comment: @Jay I rewrote my explanation hoping to make them clearer, thanks for the help!

Comment: I think you need more troublshooting. For example, does this code within this `if (sessionIdsToProcess.isNotEmpty())` run on the second change? As mentioned above, it would help us to help you to know where the code is failing and why, so stepping trough the code to know what code is and isn't executing may be very revealing.

Comment: @Jay I've added logs inside the code and added them below. The code fails to delete any data on the second change with this code `session.timeIntervals.deleteAllFromRealm()` , because as shown in the logs,  `Session time intervals count = 0`. Thanks for your time!

Comment: I may be overlooking something but won't `sessionIdsToProcess` always be empty `sessionIdsToProcess.isNotEmpty()` since it's not initialized with any data? `private val sessionIdsToProcess = mutableSetOf<String>()`

Comment: @Jay It's actually filled elsewhere when some changes occur. It's in place only to avoid infinite loops with the change listener.

Comment: A `private val sessionIdsToProcess` would indicate it's a private var to this object and not accessible elsewhere (hence 'private')

Comment: @Jay out of simplicity I've tried to remove as much code as possible and basically I have a public function to notify my Session changes `fun startChanged(session: Session) { this.sessionIdsToProcess.add(session.id) }`

Comment: Reducing the code is great and appreciated but we also need to be able to duplicate the issue with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). As is, we cannot replicate the issue with your code. As mentioned above initializing sessionIdsToProcess to nil will cause the code to fail. I understand there is other code involved but your issue could be caused by that other code e.g. your code works for me and does not fail. So I would put effort in creating a short stand-alone example of the issue and update the question with it.

Comment: I've added some more code for clarity and also created a github repository to easily test the issue: https://github.com/laurentmorvillier/realmtest. Thanks!

Comment: The code in the question should reflect the issue, not an offsite resource. The reason is that links break and can change over time. Without having the actual failing code in the question, if that happens, future readers will have no idea what the issue was, making the question useless.

Comment: @Jay Code has been added in parallel to the question so I hope there is now enough. Do you think the question is understandable?

Comment: It's much better. I think you may be having an asynchronous issue with the code but the formatting makes it hard to follow. I think this line `Timber.d("executeTransactionAsync onSuccess listener...")` executes before the code in the async call finishes. Generally, code following a closure will execute before the code in the closure. More troubleshooting is needed; right after this `asyncRealm ->` output some text to console "in asyncRealm" and then try your code and see if it outputs before or after this `Timber.d("executeTransactionAsyn`. I could be wrong on this guess.

Comment: @Jay I've updated the code and the logs to reflect the change you want but it doesn't look like the onSuccess is called before. The issue is that on the second change `session.timeIntervals.deleteAllFromRealm()`does nothing because for an unknown reason `session.timeIntervals` is empty, when it shouldn't.